# Theorem 2.1 in Stein and Shakarachi Fourier Analysis.(uniqueness of Fourier Series)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, harmonic-analysis

The Book States the following Theorem:

Suppose that $f$ is an integrable function on the circle with $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all n\in $\mathbb{Z}.$ Then $f(\theta_{o})=0$ whenever $f$ is continuous at the point $\theta_{o}$.

I do not understand the statement of the theorem and how to link it with the remark preceding it which states that:
" if $f$ and $g$ have the same Fourier Coefficients, then $f$&$g$ are necessarily equal." and the book said that"by taking the difference $f - g,$ this proposition can be reformulated as: if $\hat{f}(n) = 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, then $f = 0.$"

Could anyone explain this for me?

Thanks.

Comment: To connect the statement to the remark, suppose that $f$ and $g$ have the same Fourier coefficients. Then $f-g$ is a function which has all of its Fourier coefficients equal to 0 (remember that the map $f\mapsto \hat{f}$ is linear). So to prove the statement about $f=g,$ it suffices to show that any function with all 0 Fourier coefficients is the 0 function ($g=g+0=g+f-g=f$).

Comment: Are you aware of the convention that equality of two integrable functions usually means equality almost everywhere? In general, this is all you can expect because changing a function on a set of measure $0$ does not affect its Fourier coefficients.

Comment: @Jochen...... thank u for your answer but I think it is not an answer of my above question.

Comment: Well, it is because it explains why the statement about $f(\theta_0)=0$ does not follow from "the remark preceding it".

Comment: @Jochen ...does not follow ? could you clarify please?

Comment: Are you assuming Riemann integrability? A bounded function on $[a,b]$ is Riemann integrable iff it is continuous almost everyone.

Comment: The preceding remark only implies that $f=0$ almost everywhere, i.e., there is a set $A$ with Lebesgue measure $0$ such that $f(\theta)=0$ for every $\theta \notin A$. Since it may happen that $\theta_0\in A$ you can't conclude anything about $f(\theta_0)$.

Comment: @Jochen  So could please summarize exactly your point of view?

Comment: @MathLover I think my remarks are clear enough.

Comment: @Jochen   ok as u like :)

Comment: From the text, "Our ﬁrst result disposes of the question of uniqueness: Are two functions with the same Fourier coeﬃcients necessarily equal? Indeed, a simple argument shows that if both functions are continuous, then in fact they must agree." Clearly uniqueness cannot be pointwise in general because the integrals defining the Fourier coefficients themselves cannot distinguish between two integrable functions that are equal a.e..